# placing of numbers from 2 array to a single array according to odd and even position

Tags: java, arrays

for example:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,6,7,8]
```

so it should print

```
c=[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]
```

well the out put is not coming I don't know what is wrong
I think I got wrong in loops I am assuming

```
    import java.io.*;
    class wert
    {
    public static void main(String[]ert)throws IOException
    {
    InputStreamReader ni=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(ni);
    int k=0,i;
    int y[]=new int[3];
    int u[]=new int[3];
    int c[]=new int[6];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    y[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    u[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)//even block
    {
    if(k%2==0)
    {
    c[k++]=y[i];
    }
    k++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)//odd block
    {
    if(k%2!=0)
    {
    c[k++]=u[i];
    }
    k++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(c[i]);
    }}}
```

Comment: I did a little bit of changes

Comment: `int u[]=new String[3];` this is wrong. it should be `int u[]=new int[3];`

Comment: You should always name classes with a capital letter ,please

Comment: Also please format the code while posting questions to get a quicker and better reply (just like every answer is formatted)

Comment: Just add k=0 after completion of even block and it will work fine

Comment: @AfterlifeAssassin just add K=0 after completion of even block and it will work fine. As in you current code, your k will be 6 after completion of even block, and as soon as you enter odd block , it will put first value at c[7] which is not correct.

Comment: @AshishAni resetting the value of `k` will not fix the issue as the loop runs from `i=0 to i=2` and hence will never populate for `k > 2` with only this change.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar as we reset the k=0, when it enters the odd block it will set the first value at c[1] = u[0]; which is required solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import java.io.*;
    class wert
    {
    public static void main(String[]ert)throws IOException
    {
    InputStreamReader ni=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(ni);
    int k=0,i;
    int y[]=new int[3];
    int u[]=new int[3];
    int c[]=new int[6];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    y[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    u[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    if(k%2==0)
    {
    c[k++]=y[i];
    }
    k++;
    }
    k=1;//resetting the k
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    if(k%2!=0)
    {
    c[k++]=u[i];
    }
    k++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(c[i]);
    }}}
```

Comment: sorry k should be 1 not 0

Comment: k=0 for the even case

Answer (score 0):

You're not considering the even elements of the other array in the even block and vice-versa.

I suggest you a better approach.

Loop through both the arrays, add appropriately from each array and put it.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a[] = new int[4];
int b[] = new int[4];

int c[] = new int[8];

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
  a[i] = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i)
  b[i] = sc.nextInt();

for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < a.length; i ++)
{
   c[k++] = a[i];//take from the 1st array
   c[k++] = b[i];//take from the 2nd array
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You issue is in your even for loop, your `k` increments beyond array capacity and would be even after code exits and hence odd loop wont work. You would need to reset your `k` variable to 1.

I would suggest you merge both loop into one like:

```
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++) {
    c[k++]=y[i];
    c[k++]=u[i];
}
```

Comment: Why even bother to check value of k? Why is that needed?

Comment: @SMA initially `k=0` and then you are always adding 2 elements to the array. So in every case you can rely on the fact that insertion from y[] will be in even position and from u[] in odd position.

Comment: Did you tried using `y.length` instead of `c.length`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do addition to new array in single loop as below:

```
import java.io.*;
class wert
{
    public static void main(String[]ert)throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader ni=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(ni);
        int k=0,i;
        int y[]=new int[3];
        int u[]=new int[3];
        int c[]=new int[6];
        for(i=0;
        i<3;
        i++)
        {
            y[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            u[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        }
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            c[k++]=y[i];
            c[k++]=u[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(c[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait a min u said the k is increasing beyond array what if we reset it

Comment: @AfterlifeAssassin In this case, last insertion will happen for `k=5` which will not be an issue as your array is of size 6. No change should be required.

Answer (score 0):

@AfterlifeAssassin just add K=1 after completion of even block and it will work fine. As in you current code, your k will be 6 after completion of even block, and as soon as you enter odd block , it will put first value at c[7] which is not correct.

Comment: resetting the value of k will not fix the issue as the loop runs from i=0 to i=2 and hence will never populate for k > 2 with only this change.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar as we reset the k=0, when it enters the odd block it will set the first value at c[1] = u[0]; which is required solution

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar and next value will be set at c[3]=u[1];

Comment: Yes it will start with c[1] if you reset the value of k, but k is being incremented only once. So either k will need to  be incremented twice `k+=2` to make it store next element in c[3]. Sorry if this explanation is also not clear enough.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar Sorry for wrong info, but, My  main point is to reset the K value after even block

Comment: Okay agreed that a reset will be required if insertion is to be done in two separate for loops  (Although it will not be an elegant way to do it)

Answer (score 0):

Here friends !!

complete Running Program Logic is little different

```
class nc
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a[]={1,2,3,4};      //array 1
        int b[]={5,6,7,8};       //array 2
        int c[]=new int[10];   //new Array


        int EVEN=0;
        int ODD=1;

        boolean dishq,bishq;
        int uban=1;
        int tban=1;

                dishq=true;
                bishq=true;

        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {

            if(i%2==0)
            {
                if(dishq)
                {       
                    c[i]=a[0];
                    dishq=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    c[i]=a[uban];

                    uban=uban+1;

                }

            }

            if(i%2==1)
            {

                if(bishq)
                {
                        c[i]=b[0];
                        bishq=false;
                }
                else
                {
                    c[i]=b[tban];
                    tban=tban+1;    
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<c.length-2;i++)
        System.out.println(c[i]);
    }
}
```